# Unable to launch the Exchange Management Shell after installing KB3011140

Tags: exchange-2013

So I installed KB3011140 this weekend and after rebooting to apply, I'm unable to launch the Exchange Management Shell (or the Admin Center for that matter)  I'm running Exchange 2013 SP1 CU6

The error in EMS is

```
VERBOSE: Connecting to amos.sscorp.com.

New-PSSession : [amos.sscorp.com] Processing data from remote server     amos.sscorp.com     failed with the following error

message: [ClientAccessServer=AMOS,BackEndServer=amos.sscorp.com,RequestId=7fb3067d-    6db7-420a-8e2b-e3b29e025a08,TimeSta

p=12/15/2014 1:06:06 PM]

[AuthZRequestId=ee7db1d8-e4b9-48d8-9f3e-cff5ef65107b][FailureCategory=AuthZ-TypeInitializationException] The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Authorization.InitialSessionStateBuilder' threw an exception. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

At line:1 char:1

+ New-PSSession -ConnectionURI "$connectionUri" -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Excha ...

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

+ CategoryInfo : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace)            [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : IncorrectProtocolVersion,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

The error in the event log is

```
(Process w3wp.exe, PID 17816) "Exchange AuthZPlugin Fails to finish method  GetApplicationPrivateData due to the fatal error: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Authorization.InitialSessionStateBuilder' threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.CmdletConfigurationEntries' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.CmdletConfigurationEntries..cctor()

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.CmdletConfigurationEntries.PopulateISSCmdletConfigurationEntries()

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)

at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Authorization.InitialSessionStateBuilder..cctor()

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Authorization.InitialSessionStateBuilder.Build(List`1 allCmdlets, List`1 allScripts, ExchangeRunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfig)

at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Authorization.ExchangeRunspaceConfiguration.CreateInitialSessionState()

at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Authorization.ExchangeAuthorizationPlugin.GetInitialSessionStateCore(PSSenderInfo senderInfo)

at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Authorization.ExchangeAuthorizationPlugin.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3()

at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Authorization.AuthZLogHelper.HandleExceptionAndRetry[T](String methodName, Func`1 func, Boolean throwException, T defaultReturnValue)".
```

I've tried uninstalling the KB, but since it can't connect to EMS, that fails too.

Some websites have recommended trying to connect to .../EWS/Services.wsdl but that works without issue.

My Google-foo must be weak this morning as I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Carl, it's early so I'm just guessing here, but try this page: http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://muppetbrains.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/update-exchange-2007-exchange-2013-unerwarteter-fehler-authzplugin-fails/&prev=search -- it looks to me where it says "incorrect protocol version" and "system cannot find the file specified" that it might have jacked up the registry paths for Powershell.  That page might help you there.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked through the page you sent and looked through all the errors I had, but none of them reference the registry error that's on the page you linked

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to install CU7 and reboot.  After doing so everything came back without issue.